# How do i represent bit info in C?

Tags: c

I need to store a value between 0-15 in C , 4 bits are enough for this. How can I just have a variable of 4 bits? Space is a constraint here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using a `char`. Yeah, it's 8-bits, but you can use the bit shift operators (`<<` and `>>`) to store values in the other 4 bits.

**Edit:** Per the comments below, an `unsigned char` is, in fact, preferable over `char` to avoid issues with the sign bit.

Comment: You can use bit operators to store two 4-bit values in a `char`. But you should make sure to use `unsigned char` or else you'll get wonky behavior with signed shifting.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [bitfield](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html) to store your 4 bits, however, unless you've several of them adjacent in a struct, you won't save any space over storing the value in a byte.

Comment: Even if you do have them adjacent it's not certain that the compiler will actually align them that way in memory and pack the data structure that way. Most modern compilers will specifically not pack their structures that way even if you try. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Also, there's no way to address the bitfields without using a conditional. If you do the packing into `unsigned char` yourself, then you can simply use the low bit of the index, e.g. `(i&1)<<2`, as a shift operand.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really have one 4-bit variable, but you can have 8-bit variables that store two 4-bit values, but you have to access them with a temp, meaning you don't save any space unless you have more than two:

```
uint8_t var_both;
uint8_t temp = (var_both >> 4) & 0x0F; // For first value
temp = var_both & 0x0F; // For second value
```

Answer (score 2):

As Chris Lutz specified, you can define the amount of bits that a variable uses by adding a colon and the size of it: `unsigned char myOneBitVariable:1;` and for your case 'unsigned char MyFourBitVariable:4'. I'd like to point out how **extremely difficult** this is and **why you should avoid it**.

Most modern compilers will align the space for your variables in your struct. The most general case today is 4 bytes or even 8 bytes but that varies from platform to platform and compiler to compiler. Some compilers allow you to specify the alignment of the data and its members. On GCC the keyword is `__attribute__((aligned(x)))` and on MSVC it's `__declspec(align(x))`. In most cases you will also need to specify how much the compiler should pack the structures. MSVC has the `#pragma pack(x)`directive: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1(VS.80).aspx. You can also read about MSVC alignment here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65(VS.80).aspx. GCC has its own implementation called `__attribute__ ((__packed__)`, which you might have to search around for.
An example that doesn't give you what you want, using Microsoft's compiler:

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#error This alignment solution / packing solution is only valid on MSC
#endif /* ifndef _MSC_VER */

#define M_ALIGN(x)    __declspec(align(x))

struct S64Bits
{
    unsigned char MyOneBitVariable:1;
    int My32BitInt;
};

// MSVC specific implementation of data-packing in a type.
#pragma pack(1)
struct S32Bits
{
    D_ALIGN(1) int My16BitVariable:16;
    D_ALIGN(1) unsigned char Padding8Bits;
    D_ALIGN(1) unsigned char MyOneBitVariable1:1;
    D_ALIGN(1) unsigned char MyOneBitVariable2:1;
    D_ALIGN(1) unsigned char MyOneBitVariable3:1;
    D_ALIGN(1) unsigned char MyOneBitVariable4:1;
    D_ALIGN(1) unsigned char MyFourBitVariable:4;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

'sizeof(S64Bits)' should be 8, which it is. 'sizeof(S32Bits)' should be 4, **it isn't**. On msvc the latter is 6 bytes. The behavior is also compiler-specific and often have compiler-unique directives. This kind of behavior almost never gives you what you want. I often use a macro to make sure that structures that I require to be of a certain size really are:

```
#define TEST_TYPE_SIZE(Type, Size) assert(sizeof(Type) == Size);
```

That I will use below all my data-types where I try to specify the exact size of them. However, relying on a structure being any size other than sizeof(mystructure) is coding that will likely lead to difficult to debug errors. Alignment-compiler directives are best suited to be used to align data to cache-line size and similar efficiency issues.

Karl Bielefeldt provides a good natural solution of storing 4-bit values into an uint8 using bit shift operations, use those instead.

Comment: -1 for nonportable hacks, and another -1 for use of bitfields if I could. Simply do the bit arithmetic yourself. It's easier, portable, results in well-defined behavior, and not error-prone.

Comment: Nonportable hacks? I clearly state about compiler-specifics. When it comes to packing data in manners it is very important to know how each compiler packs and aligns data. The question is how to use 4 bits only since space is a constraint and I try to provide information regarding the complexity of getting exactly the size of memory you want. Could you please elaborate your critisism a bit more?

Comment: @R..: Perhaps you didn't read my comments regarding the difficulty on achieving correct sizes using these methods? Or maybe you didn't read my text regarding relying on structure-sizes? I thought that they pretty well explained why you shouldn't use these kind of solutions. My argumentation wasn't PRO using these solutions, they are against it.

Comment: Comments on the difficulty don't reflect that there are much more fundamental reasons why none of the approaches you suggested should ever be used. I don't see any value in even presenting them, especially when you've left it to the reader to draw a conclusion that they should not be used.

Comment: @R..: I changed post, hopefully it will be more clearer now. I still can't get those pragmas to be ordinary text though. Thanks for the additional feedback.

Comment: Removed the -1. I still don't think it's all that great an answer, but it's also not really misleading/harmful. Only other change I might suggest is to explicitly state where you're using compiler extensions and other nonportable stuff.

Comment: @R..: Added even more clarifications regarding compiler extensions and similar :)

Answer (score 0):

The term for a half byte is a nibble. So here:

```
struct two_nibbles {
  unsigned a :4;
  unsigned b :4;
}
```

You have to name your two variables `x.a` and `x.b` (but change `x` to whatever), but you'll save a little space. You might want to check, though - I think the compiler would make sure that `sizeof(struct two_nibbles) == sizeof(char)` but it might not, so you might have to add more nibbles to make it worth the space.

Comment: By defining a and b as unsigned wont they automatically be integers, hence occupying 4+ bytes?

Comment: no - you can specify the exact with of unsigned ints in a struct, by using the notation shown here by Chris. Each of the fields a and b in the example above will use 4 bits. It's important to remember though, that the compiler might add padding to the end of such a struct.

Comment: The compiler **will** (in practice) make them 4+ bytes. You should use `unsigned char a:4; unsigned char b:4;` or better yet throw out bitfields (one of the stupidest, most useless things in the C language) and do the bit arithmetic yourself so you get well-defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Are you ever going to want to take the address of the 4-bit values? If so, you need to store them in a "proper" data type, such as a char.